# Add object to array within NSMutableDictionary loaded from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I have an array inside a NSMutableDictionary and i want to add objects to it. With my current approach I get an error saying that the array is immutable.

I think the problem lies when I´m saving the dictionary to NSUserDefaults. I´m retrieving the is it a `NSDictionary` but I am at the same time creating a new `NSMutableDictionary` with the contents.

However, the array seems to be immutable. How do I replace an array inside of a dictionary?

My dictionary looks like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];

NSDictionary *dict = @{

                     @"firstKey": @{
                                     @"theArray":array,
                                   }

                      };

NSMutableDictionary *mutDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];
```

I am trying to add objects like this:

```
[[[mutDict objectForKey:@"firstKey"] objectForKey:@"theArray"] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]];
```

I am able to add objects to the array inside `mutDict` before its saved to `NSUserDefaults`

The error message I get when I try to add to the array inside the dictionary after loading it from NSUserDefaults:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

Comment: you have two dictionaries here. Key "theArray" is from second dictionary. Do you want to add more key/values to this second dictionary, right?

Comment: I want to add more values inside "array" i.e add more objects to the value for the key @"theArray". Am I making sense?

Comment: Okay, in this way you can just replace whole array that have key "theArray". E.g. Init mutable array with array (your "theArray") add items and set value to dictionary key "theArray"

Comment: Ok, can you give me an example where I can replace the array? Do I need to remove the old one and then add the new? Many thanks.

Comment: Your code is working fine, it adds a new number 5 to the array  
`2015-07-11 11:40:05.599 TestC[422:4891] {
    firstKey =     {
        theArray =         (
            0,
            5
        );
    };
}`

Comment: The problem is when I load the dictionary from NSUSerDefaults, it seems the array has become immutable. So I can't add to it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/dictionaryForKey:) for `dictionaryForKey:` says on NSUserDefaults:

> **Special Considerations**
>
> The returned dictionary and its contents are immutable, even if the values you >originally set were mutable.

So when you retrieve your dictionary from NSUserDefaults the dictionary itself and all of the collections inside it are immutable. You can make the top level dictionary mutable (which I assume you are doing), but that won't propagate down into the now immutable NSArrays which are values in the dictionary.

The only way to get around this is to go through the dictionary that's returned and replace the immutable NSArrays with their mutable counterparts. It might look something like this.

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)deepMutableCopyOfDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [dictionary mutableCopy];
    for (id key in [mutableDictionary allKeys]) {
        id value = mutableDictionary[key];
        if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            // If the value is a dictionary make it mutable and call recursively
            mutableDictionary[key] = [self deepMutableCopyOfDictionary:dictionary[key]];
        }
        else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            // If the value is an array, make it mutable
            mutableDictionary[key] = [(NSArray *)value mutableCopy];
        }
    }
    return mutableDictionary;
}
```

To be honest though it sounds like you're using NSUserDefaults for something a lot more complex then it is intended for. If you want to persist complex data structures then you should look into something like Core Data, or if that looks to be a bit overkill take a look at [NSKeyedArchiver](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/).

Comment: Great answer, precisely what I was looking for. Thank you! Will consider replacing NSUserDefaults for this use-case.

Answer (score 1):

You can add object directly to the array:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];

NSDictionary *dict = @{

                     @"firstKey": @{
                                     @"theArray":array,
                                   }

                      };

NSMutableDictionary *mutDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];

//Since Objective-C objects are always passed by reference (using pointers) you can add object to the array
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:55]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift example of adding object to array which is part of a dictionary.

```
let arr = [0] // note that initial array may be immutable

var dict = ["fK": ["a":arr]] // even if "arr" will be mutable, but "dict" immutable

dict["fK"]!["a"]!.append(3) // this will not work. "dict" must be mutable

println(dict) //[fK: [a: [0, 3]]]
```

Another approach

```
var arr = [0] // initial array must be mutable

var dict = ["fK": ["a":arr]] // in both cases dictionary must be mutable 

arr.append(3)

let newArr = arr

dict["fK"]!["a"]! = newArr // because we change it's content

println(dict) //[fK: [a: [0, 3]]]
```